# Problems with DEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, eigenvalues

I have the following problem

$\frac{c_p q_m}{A}\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial t}+\rho  c_p \frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial x}-\lambda  \frac{\partial^2 T(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0$

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the differential operator

```
DEigensystem[D[u[x], {x, 2}] - D[u[x], x], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 4]
```

which works and gives the following result

\begin{bmatrix}{}
 0 & \frac{1}{4} \left(-1-36 \pi ^2\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(-1-16 \pi ^2\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(-1-4 \pi ^2\right) \\
 e^x & e^{x/2} (6 \pi  \cos (3 \pi  x)-\sin (3 \pi  x)) & e^{x/2} (4 \pi  \cos (2 \pi  x)-\sin (2 \pi  x)) & e^{x/2} (2 \pi  \cos (\pi  x)-\sin (\pi  x)) \\
\end{bmatrix}

but this does not work

```
DEigensystem[D[u[x], {x, 2}] - a D[u[x], x], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 4]
```

Why?

I constructed a weird test case

```
Table[DEigensystem[D[u[x], {x, 2}] - a D[u[x], x], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 2], {a, 0, 20}]
```

this does work up to a=8

Comment: So what is the mathematical form of `u`?  This is needed for us to check the eigensystem.

Comment: It's the temperatur. But does it matter?

Comment: If it suffices for you to obtain the eigensystem for numeric `a` then you should have a look at `NDEigensystem `.